# Changing furigana in Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: fonts, styles, microsoft-word-2011

I've finished typing a document in Word and when I printed it I realized that the furigana is way too small for easy reading.

Is there a way to **globally** change the size of all furigana for a complete document or a section? The only way I can do it so far is to change one by one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straight way of adjusting the size of all the furiganas in a document. But there is a way.

Let's say you have the following text with furigana.

> 漢字(かんじ)のふりがなを調整(ちょうせい)します。

Press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, or go into Preferences > View and check the Show > "Field code" box. Then you'll see the text transformed to:

> { eq * jc2 * "Font:ＭＳ 明朝" * hps12 \o\ad(\s\up 11(かんじ),漢字)}のふりがなを{ eq * jc2 * "Font:ＭＳ 明朝" * hps12 \o\ad(\s\up 11(ちょうせい),調整)}します。

This is how Word stores markup information for each furigana. What we're interested in is the `hps12` bit: it specifies the size of the furigana. If you replace it with `hps20`:

> { eq * jc2 * "Font:ＭＳ 明朝" * hps20 \o\ad(\s\up 11(かんじ),漢字)}のふりがなを{ eq * jc2 * "Font:ＭＳ 明朝" * hps20 \o\ad(\s\up 11(ちょうせい),調整)}します。

and press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> again:

> 漢字(かんじ)のふりがなを調整(ちょうせい)します。

the size of the furigana should be adjusted. As far as I've experimented, hps12 corresponds to a font size of 6pt, and hps20 to 10pt.

Note: on Windows, the shortcut for toggling field code is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I can't believe that MS didn't think of adding this feature.